# How to connect two existing tables by selected field (not integer but string) with django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make a relationship one to one between the tables by a selected field. I have parcel data with identification field and table with permission attributes containing other data, referencing to parcel identification ield. I am trying to connect these tables with one to one:

```
class Parcels(models.Model):
      identification = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
      area = models.FloatField()

class Permissions(models.Model):
      permission_number = models.Charfield(max_length=40)
      identification  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      parcels = models.One(Parcels, to_field='identification',null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then I am encapsulating the Parcel serializer in Permissions serializer to be sent to django REST_API. However this does not work. The idea here is that I am periodically adding Permission data to database and need to automatically join the parcel data by identification number. How can I do it in django?

Comment: there should be models.OneToOneField(..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by creating a table that is updated whenever there is an update command called. In the project folder I have created managemend/command folder with a custom script to run update. in that script I have defined a function such as:

```
def merge_tables(self):
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE merged_table")
     cursor.execute(INSERT INTO merged_table SELECT data FROM parcel INNER JOIN permissions ON permisions.identyfikator=parcel.identyfikator")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use

```
models.ForeignKey(Parcels, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Since "identification" is unique. Use parcels_id when querying.

Otherwise, if you absolutely need a OneToOneField, in models.py import

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

Then,

```
class Permissions(models.Model):
  permission_number = models.Charfield(max_length=40)
  identification  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  parcels = models.OneToOneField(Parcels, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  
@receiver(post_save, sender=Parcels)
def create_parcel_permission(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Permissions.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Parcels)
def save_parcel_permission(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.permission.save()
```

receiver (signals) documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/)

Comment: That didnt help. These 2 models come independently and are updated independently. I need perhaps to make a new model that is a query output from connecting those by identification field?

Comment: Yes, that would work as well, but you wouldn't need to query if I understand your problem correctly. Instead create a bridge table/model with 2 foreign key fields: parcels_id and permissions_identification.      Can you please clarify: does each parcel have 1 permission and each permission 1 parcel? Or can a parcel have more than 1 permission and a permission more than 1 parcel?

Comment: I have used db_column argument to connect via other than id key. However this key is not integer and now this is where I got stuck. I have instead made a raw sql query to create another table as an output from the other 2

Comment: I don't understand how that would get you stuck, or why you need to use something other that id. You could query by id and retrieve/use whatever column for that record. If you absolutely need to use the string lookup value, you can use the bit representation or another numerical representation of string and annotate your records with that unique integer sequence